# .net installs but framework not found in folder

Tags: .net

I just installed .net 4.6.1, and the installer completed successfully.  According to the Add/Remove programs dialog, I have .net 4.6.1 is installed (more precisely 4.6.01055).

However, in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` and `Framework64` folders, the most recent version is 4.0.30319.  This is also the only one recognised by my app if I give it a `my_app.exe.config` file forcing it to use a specific .net version.

Where has version 4.6.1 gone and how can I get my app to use it?

Comment: Clearly I'm still not getting the hang of SO.  Please can somebody explain why this was a bad question.

Comment: I thought it was a reasonable question - certainly well asked. All I can think is people maybe felt it didn't show the requisite level of research. However, they are probably forgetting how hard it is to google for information like this, as you naturally are unaware of the relevant keywords like "CLR".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the CLR version.

The .NET Framework consists of a CLR (Common Language Runtime) and a set of libraries. The CLR has fewer releases than the libraries, so the version number tends to be older than the Framework version number.

The CLR is v4.0 for all versions of 4.x of the Framework.

Similarly the CLR for Frameworks 2.0 -> 3.5 is v2.0.

For background - the CLR is a "virtual machine" similar to the JVM (Java Virtual Machine).

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karinm/2008/11/10/whats-the-difference-between-clr-and-net-framework/ for a good description of the relationship between the CLR and the Framework.